# C++ initialize anonymous struct

Tags: c++, struct, anonymous-types

I'm still earning my C++ wings; My question is if I have a struct like so:

```
struct Height
{
    int feet;
    int inches;
};
```

And I then have some lines like so:

```
Height h = {5, 7};
Person p("John Doe", 42, "Blonde", "Blue", h);
```

I like the initialization of structs via curly braces, but I'd prefer the above be on one line, in an anonymous Height struct. How do I do this? My initial naive approach was:

```
Person p("John Doe", 42, "Blonde", "Blue", Height{5,7});
```

This didn't work though. Am I very far off the mark?

Comment: This may just be an example, but, it's probably better to store the `Height` as a single `inches` field.  When you need feet you can convert that to feet; it's just far easier to deal with a single unit than to juggle multiple units, especially since as it is now you can have multiple values that are equal but do not have the same representation (e.g., `{2, 3}` and `{1, 15}`).

Comment: C++1x comes with [uniform initialization syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Uniform_initialization) which would support something like this. It's quite likely that your compiler already supports it.

Comment: Instead of `Height{5,7}` in the Person constructor, specify `(struct Height){5,7}` (if you're passing by reference) (or `&(struct Height){5,7}` if you're passing a pointer). You're basically casting the initializer list to the desired type. It's a C99+ feature, but should be usable with C++ as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't, at least not in present-day C++; the brace initialization is part of the initializer syntax and can't be used elsewhere.

You can add a constructor to `Height`:

```
struct Height
{
    Height(int f, int i) : feet(f), inches(i) { }
    int feet, inches;
};
```

This allows you to use:

```
Person p("John Doe", 42, "Blonde", "Blue", Height(5, 7));
```

Unfortunately, since `Height` is no longer an aggregate, you can no longer use the brace initialization.  The constructor call initialization is just as easy, though:

```
Height h(5, 7);
```

Comment: Neat. I didn't know structs could have constructors/initializer-lists.

Comment: @byte:  A `struct` is exactly the same thing as a `class`.  The only difference is that the base classes and members are by default public for a `struct` and private for a `class`.

Answer (score 4):

Standard C++ (C++98, C++03) doesn't support this.

g++ supports is a language extension, and I seem to recall that C++0x will support it. You'd have to check the syntax of the g++ language extension and/or possibly C++0x.

For currently standard C++, just name the `Height` instance, as you've already done, then use the name.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Is it automatically provided, or do you have to define a constructor that accepts an `initializer_list` argument?

Comment: @Ben: no, you don't have to define a constructor to get the C++0x syntax. much of the point/goal is to have a *uniform* syntax that works the same in most every situation. check out the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Uniform_initialization) given by @sbi earlier. Or, if you want the details, the latest draft is available from the [C++ committe pages](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/), in PDF format.