# Attempting to initialise map that takes an object as value within a constructor

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

I've been looking around trying to solve this problem, and the closest I got was this question [How do you initialize a map which takes a struct as value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396560/how-do-you-initialize-a-map-which-takes-a-struct-as-value), however it didn't seem to work. 
If anybody knows of a solution then I'd love to know, otherwise I'll lay out my problem. I would like to create a batch of chess pieces, and to do this I have created a class 'ChessBoard' and a class 'Pieces' which is a superclass which all the pawns and knights etc. inherit. This is "ChessBoard.h")

```
    class ChessBoard {
protected:
    map< vector<int>, Piece* > chess_pieces;
public:
    ChessBoard();
};
```

Now I also have a subclass of 'Piece', which is 'Pawn'. I want to assign an element of type Pawn as one of the chess_pieces. So, within the chessboard constructor I have the lines:

```
    ChessBoard::ChessBoard()
{
    /* Initialise white pieces */
    /* First we set up the pawns: */
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        vector<int> v = {1, j};
        chess_pieces[v] = new Pawn;
    }
}
```

However, the compiler gives me a warning, calling me up on the 'new Pawn' assignment, saying that I am 'Allocating an object of abstract class type Pawn'. Is this not allowed? I have defined the 'Pawn' class with the default constructor and the class 'Piece' also has the default constructor. Also, I have made sure to include the line

```
class Pawn: public Piece {
```

in the Pawn class declaration.
If anyone knows how to get this going I'd love to know, thanks for any help you folks can give me!

Comment: Does Pawn provide implementations for all pure virtual methods declared in Piece?

Comment: that was it! I forgot to implement the virtual methods, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class Piece must have defined in it a pure virtual method.  something like `virtual int foo() = 0;` you will need to implement all of the pure virtual methods from class Piece in our class Pawn in order for 'new Pawn` to work.

It is always best to provide as much detail as possible in your question, or others will have to guess at your real issue.

Here is a quick example program to illustrate the issue and the output of the compiler:

```
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece() {}
    virtual ~Piece() {}

    virtual int foo() = 0;
};

class Pawn: public Piece
{
};

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    Pawn *p = new Pawn;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}

:!g++ virtual.cpp
virtual.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char*)’:
virtual.cpp:16: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Pawn’
virtual.cpp:11: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Pawn’:
virtual.cpp:7: note:    virtual int Piece::foo()
```

Comment: ahhhh yes! I do have a pure virtual method, I didn't know that was a problem. Thank you for the help, I've been banging my head against the wall for a good while. I'll try and make sure to add more detail next time. (sorry I can't vote up, my rep's too low!)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you haven't overridden all abstract member functions from `Piece`. Make sure you actually do override exactly the signature of the abstract function rather than a similar one: the argument types and the constness of the members cannot differ.

That said, you probably shouldn't use a `std::map<...>` to represent your board! Using a two dimensional array (or a one-dimensional array with suitable access functions for the rows and the columns) is probably a better choice. If you insist in using a `std::map<...>`, consider using a `std::pair<int, int>` or an `std::array<int, 2>` as key.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! I didn't clock that it was my virtual problems which were the crux of it. Aye my vector method is kinda shaky, your suggestions look a lot more robust. Thanks!